# Big radio button design in CSS

Tags: html, css

When you hover your mouse there should be red border on the selection and when you click on the radio button it should put a check on it with a circle just like the image.

So far on my HTML and  my CSS I put styles where in I am trying to target my form-check But this one did not work and my design is not aligning with what I want. How can I achieve the same as the image above?

```css
.form-check {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: padding: 14px 15px 14px 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"].form-check-input {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="b-container">
    <h3 class="q-item">Do you love web development and mobile development?</h3>
    <div class="form-check ps-0">
      <label class="form-check-label q_radio">Yes 
        <input class="form-check-input" name="" type="radio" value="Yes"> 
      </label>
      <label class="form-check-label q_radio">No 
        <input class="form-check-input" name="" type="radio" value="No" checked> 
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet here. No need for JSFiddle

Comment: I added bootstrap. Edit the snippet and make a [mcve]

Comment: have a look at https://codepen.io/imohkay/embed/wyxuB?height=366&theme-id=1787&slug-hash=wyxuB&default-tab=result&user=imohkay

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons are [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) and therefore beyond the reach of CSS.

A common solution to this problem is to hide the native radio button and reconstruct it with other (styleable) elements, positioned in the place of the original.

In the snippet below, the original radio is hidden via `visibility: hidden`, and a `::after` pseudo-element is used to create a red circle positioned over it.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden; /* hide the native radio button */
}

label > span {
  margin: 0 1rem; /* leave room for the big button */
}

input[type=radio]::after { /* use a pseudo-element to build a replacement */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  
  /* make it a circle */
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;

  /* white bg, grey border */
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px grey;
  
  /* fun fact: child visibility can be overridden */
  visibility: visible;
  
  /* alignment */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* text treatment */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* animate the box shadow change just for fun */
  transition: box-shadow 0.25s;
}

input[type=radio]:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px red;
}

input[type=radio]:checked::after {
  content: '✔'; /* display a checkmark if it's selected */
  
  box-shadow: none;
  
  /* red bg, white fg */
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label><input name="x" type="radio" /> <span>A radio button</span></label>
<label><input name="x" type="radio" /> <span>A radio button</span></label>
<label><input name="x" type="radio" /> <span>A radio button</span></label>
<label><input name="x" type="radio" /> <span>A radio button</span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/89c922788852d6b874d33269fe34ffc4

```css
/* For demo only */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 0 40px; /* For demo only */
}

.question-box__question {
  position: relative;
}
.question-box__question:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.question__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.question__label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.question__label:hover {
  border-color: #cc3300;
}
.question__label:before, .question__label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.question__label:before {
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.question__input:checked + .question__label:before {
  background-color: #cc3300;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
.question__input:checked + .question__label:after {
  top: 20px;
  left: 17px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1">Do you love web development?</h1>
<div class="question-box">
  <div class="question-box__question">
    <input class="question__input" id="r1" type="radio" name="web">
    <label class="question__label" for="r1">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="question-box__question">
    <input class="question__input" id="r2" type="radio" name="web">
    <label class="question__label" for="r2">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```